# Keycloak realm role mappings: Inherited Roles and Default Role

Tags: authentication, authorization, keycloak

So I am using Keycloak for authentication and authorization of my project's microservice called QMS.
I currently have 3 roles:

- `default-roles-qms` - automatically created, can't be deleted or edited
- `manager`
- `developer`

`manager` and `developer` are trivial and created by me.

I have 2 users: Tom(`manager`) and Dick(`developer`).

Now I have two questions and one concern:

Question 1: What exactly is this `default-roles-qms` and why can't I make another role as default or edit this role? Why do I need to have this pre-defined default role and no other?

Question 2: If I remove the `default-roles-qms` mapping from a user, their OIDC token does not bring the `aud: account` attribute and also the `resource_access` object that I need for authorization.
URL to fetch OIDC token => `"http://{host}:{port}/auth/realms/QMS/protocol/openid-connect/token"`

Concern: While adding a user, a non default role, namely manager gets inherited intermittently which is never intended and shows up in a developer's role mappings as shown in the image.
P.S. In this image I deliberately added the manager role to show where it shows up, because the incident is intermittent.

Can anybody please help with these?

[Wrongly inherited role for a user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqER6.png)

All the steps that I tried are just as above.

What I expected:
I should be able to set a role as default, namely `developer`. But this is less of a concern.
The main concern is that apart from a default role, no other role should be inherited by a new user.

I'll be happy to provide more details in case.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: What exactly is this default-roles-qms and why can't I make another role as default or edit this role? Why do I need to have this pre-defined default role and no other?

Keycloak uses "default-roles-{realm_name}" in order to manage default roles in your realm. It is a composite role, therefore you can assign other roles to it. All roles that compose a "default-roles-qms" are assigned to every realm user by default.

To make some role default:

- in the Admin panel select "Realm roles"->"default-roles-qms"
- press "Assign role" button and select the role you want to make default.

> Question 2: If I remove the default-roles-qms mapping from a user, their OIDC token does not bring the aud: account attribute and also the resource_access object that I need for authorization. URL to fetch OIDC token => "http://{host}:{port}/auth/realms/QMS/protocol/openid-connect/token"

When you open "default-roles-qms", you will already find some roles appended to it. These roles are used by Keycloak itself in order to function properly. So when you removed mapping, you have disabled some of Keycloak functionality.